# How does the <img> tag behave with its siblings?

Tags: html, css

I have a question about how do `<input>`or any box behave next to `<img>` tags. What I mean is that I expected the `input` to be next to the `img`, at the top, but it wasn´t, instead it was below, to the right, or kind of. I´ve been told to put `float: left` to the `img` tag, but I wanted to know why it happens or at least why floating the `img` solves it.

here´s the snippet so you can check yourselves:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/413/PNG/128/Facebook_41212.png" alt="">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="url">
</div>
```

Comment: the key word: *baseline alignment*

Comment: float: left from my understanding will just say force the element to go left in your case within the parent, causing the FB image to go left.  The reason why you see the input below is because the image has a naturally higher height than the input box, hence you see the input box is lower even though the image will have a float left if you add it. If your concerned about the alignment of where the input is, try add vertical-align: middle on the input box. Hope that makes sense.